# Inception - mxnet model

Tags: python, ubuntu, kaggle, mxnet

I am new to image classification. I am trying to solve a problem on kaggle using mxnet in python. I was trying to run a script code which is one of the solutions for that problem. 
Code was like :

```
prefix="Inception/Inception-7"
num_round=1
network=model.FeedForward.load(prefix,num_round,ctx=mx.gpu(),numpy_batch_size=bx)
```

It is showing error :

> MXNetError: [15:23:58] src/io/local_filesys.cc:149: Check failed:
>   allow_null  LocalFileSystem: fail to open
>   "/Inception/Inception-7-symbol.json"

I have even changed path in the "prefix" like :

```
prefix="/home/Inception"
```

But still I am not understanding why it is not opening the `.json` file and showing the error. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: what is the complete path to your actual `.json`?

Comment: /home/Inception/Inception-7-symbol.json

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to run this notebook https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/notebooks/predict-with-pretrained-model.ipynb

You need to first download the pre-trained model from https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-model-gallery/blob/master/imagenet-1k-inception-bn.md before this notebook can run.